# How to define sets, parameters and constraints in pyomo

Tags: python, algorithm, constraints, pyomo

I have a list of asset returns.

```
Re=[0.5346,0.5064,1.0838,0.7665,0.9463,0.7047,0.6735,0.5294,0.7697,0.7299,0.99,1.0856,0.9052,0.3827,0.3804,1.0271,0.9431,0.538,0.9313,0.9423]
```

I want to maximize the following objective:

$Re(w)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}Re_{i}$

and constraints are:

(i) Full utilization of capital:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}w_{k}v_{k}=1$

where v_{k} is a binary variable, which is 1 if any of asset k is held, and 0 otherwise.

(ii) Cardinality constraint:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}v_{k}=q$

where q ∈ [q1, q2] is the desired number of assets in the portfolio.

(iii) No short selling constraint:

$w_{k}\ge 0$ for k=1,2,...,n.

(iv) Lower and upper bounds defining the proportion of the
capital that can be invested in a single asset. For avoiding very
small investments in several assets and at the same time to
maintain sufficient diversification of the funds, the bounds of
investment in individual assets are specified as:

$l_{k}v_{k} \le w_{k} \le u_{k}v_{k}$ for k=1,2,...,n.

In this example, it is assumed that the desired number of assets in the portfolio specified by investors is between 7 and 10, i.e.

7 ≤ q ≤ 10. The lower and upper bounds to be invested in
each asset k are set as l_{k} = 0.01 and u_{k} = 0.3, respectively.

I tried to solve this problem as follows:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
from pyomo.environ import Var, NonNegativeReals 


# Defining the model
model=pyo.ConcreteModel()

# set 
model.i=pyo.Set(initialize=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12','a13','a14','a15','a16','a17','a18','a19','a20'])

#parameters
model.Re=pyo.Param(model.i, initialize={'a1':0.5346,'a2':0.5064,'a3':1.0838,'a4':0.7665,'a5':0.9463,'a6':0.7047,'a7':0.6735,'a8':0.5294,'a9':0.7697,'a10':0.7299,'a11':0.99,'a12':1.0856,'a13':0.9052,'a14':0.3827,'a15':0.3804,'a16':1.0271,'a17':0.9431,'a18':0.538,'a19':0.9313,'a20':0.9423})
re=model.Re
# Decision variable

model.w=pyo.Var(model.i, within=NonNegativeReals)
w=model.w
model.v=pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.Binary)
v=model.v
model.q=pyo.Var(model.i, domain=pyo.Integers, bounds=(7,10))
q=model.q

# Objective Function
def Objective_rule(model,i):
    return sum(re[i]*w[i] for i in model.i)
model.Obj=pyo.Objective(rule=Objective_rule, sense=pyo.maximize) 


# Constraints

def Constraint1(model,i):
    return sum(w[i]*v[i] for i in model.i)==1
model.Const1=pyo.Constraint(model.i, rule=Constraint1 )

def Constraint2(model,i):
    return sum(v[i] for i in model.i)==7
model.Const2=pyo.Constraint(model.i, rule=Constraint2 )

def Constraint3(model,i):
    return (.01<=w[i]<=.3 for i in model.i)
model.Const3=pyo.Constraint(model.i, rule=Constraint3 )

#results
Solver=SolverFactory('cplex_direct')
results=Solver.solve(model)
print(results)
```

But this code doesn't work! I tried a lot to solve this problem, but unfortunately I could not.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 3 problems, one in each of the functions to generate the rules for the constraints:

1. For Constraint1, the function shouldn't be receiving *i* as an argument. According to this `\sum_{k=1}^{n}w_{k}v_{k}=1`, you only have one constraint, but you are trying to create one for each *i* (or *k* in the equation). Accordingly, `pyo.Constraint(model.i, rule=Constraint1 )` shouldn't receive *model.i* as argument.
2. For Constraint2, the exact same explanation as the previous one.
3. For Constraint3, you have to split it in two: the le and the ge parts.

So, I changed the Constraints functions as follows, and it worked for me. I didn't check the resto of the model, but I got 4.121233 as optimal value using gurobi.

```
def Constraint1(model):
    return sum(w[i]*v[i] for i in model.i)==1
model.Const1=pyo.Constraint(rule=Constraint1 )

def Constraint2(model):
    return sum(v[i] for i in model.i)==7
model.Const2=pyo.Constraint(rule=Constraint2 )

def Constraint3(model,i):
    return 0.01<=w[i]
model.Const3=pyo.Constraint(model.i, rule=Constraint3 )

def Constraint4(model,i):
    return w[i]<=0.3
model.Const4=pyo.Constraint(model.i, rule=Constraint4 )
```